# Overview table on the Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an Android app with a MapFragment displaying Google Maps and I would like to add small table to one of bottom corners which would show sort of overview (just a few text fields) with number of markers and maybe other information. I want the table to be there all the time at the same spot whether I move the map center anywhere. 
What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: use framelayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add another view to your layout (sounds like `recyclerView` that holds the list of markers is what you need). Just make sure to call `YourView.bringToFront()` after `OnMapReady()` is called. If needed add padding to your map so you won't hide the Google logo with the method `GoogleMap.setPadding()`.